# How to access the REST api of Shopware

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to get into the REST api of Shopware. I type http://my-shop-url/api/articles, and I am then asked for a username and password. This is where I'm stuck because I don't know where to get those credentials. I've tried my Shopware id and password but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to pass the bearer token which you can request via

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the checkbox in the user edit module for api-users.

After that you will be able to copy your assigned key from there and use it for the api-login

Comment: I did that and i still get tthis box of username and pasword. If the api key is the pasword what is the user then?

Comment: @KristinaKoj the user ist the login of your shopware user

Comment: I tried that and its not working... is it a Windows bug or something? Is there i should change in the code? And if yes in which folder exactly?

Comment: @KristinaKoj it works from scratch. Just access `domain.tld/api/articles`. I just tried it myself and it works like a charm.